# WooCommerce: Shortcode to display product WITHOUT description?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently using the shortcode [product_page id=""] to display one of my products on the homepage of my website, but the issue is that it also pulls all the description etc. Is there a way to just pull the product, images, short excerpt and "add to cart" buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS. I did it in my site to hide the prices and add a custom one.

This was my code

```
.page-id-27413 .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
    display: none;
}
```

So I really think it will work for the description. 
You only need the **page id** and the **class** of the element you want to hide.

If it doesn't work, please share your site so I can make some simple tests.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I found an easier way though. I used a plugin that lets me control the CSS for each individual page. Then I just "display:none" for all the parts I wanted to hide.